# Getting Facebook page posts of the last hour/day etc

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to specify a time span for the posts returned by `GET /v2.x/{page-id}/feed`?
For example, I want all the posts of the last hour and only those...

EDIT: Just found the `since` and `until` fields for the feed. However, this only seems to apply to posts, not to comments on those posts...
Any way to apply the time span to both posts and comments, regardless?
Ideally, I would get a chronological list of messages (whether posts or comments) for the last X time units.

Answer (score 0):

Graph API returns comments in same order as selected on actual post|picture|etc..
I already searched alot about this. Then i went for a stupid but simple solution. I can show you if you are willing to made 2 requests to graph api to get comments

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear, if I selected `since=yesterday` and `until=today` your method would return comments that were made today on a post that was originally created last month? This is the behavior that I'm interested in.

Comment: With my method You will get latest comments on Post|Picture|etc.. you can set number of comments to return in limit as well.

Comment: Yeah, I figured how to do this is as well, but thanks anyway. What I'm looking for is a way to get the latest (or within specified timeframe) comments on **any** post of a page, not on a selected one.

Comment: I am doing the same as you, i am getting all latest posts on timeline and then getting latest comments on these posts.

Comment: You may be doing what you're saying, but it is not what I'm interested in. I need more than the latest posts. There can be comments today on a post from last month. How do you get those comments?
If your latest posts are today's posts, you will miss a comment (made today) on that post from last month.

Comment: alright , now i get it clearly, i am exploring facebook SDK now a days. so i will mention if i get the answer to it..

Comment: Are you only displaying these comments somewhere or storing them aswell??

Comment: Ok, thanks. My plan is to also store them, but it will be extremely unpractical to go through the stored ones individually and check for new comments, if that's what you're suggesting. There has to be a better solution.

Comment: if you are going to store then just store count with them and while looking for new one you can use filter for new comments only based on counts while making api request.